# custom ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter not invoked

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

Pages that have explicit roles get 403, and my custom JwtAuthenticationConverter is not invoked.
How come?

Im using keycloak as oauth2 provider, and im using oauth2Login in order to prompt login page.
i use the same code that is in the [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/html/webflux-oauth2.html#webflux-oauth2-login-openid-provider-configuration) docs.

```
package com.eLoomina.gateway.security

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import java.util.stream.Collectors


@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig {
    companion object {
        @Suppress("JAVA_CLASS_ON_COMPANION")
        @JvmStatic
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass.enclosingClass)
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/login", "/").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/login/with-role").hasRole("populate")
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login().and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor())
        return http.build()
    }

    fun grantedAuthoritiesExtractor(): Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> {
        val extractor = KeycloakRealmRoleConverter()
        return ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(extractor)
    }

    class KeycloakRealmRoleConverter : JwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        override fun extractAuthorities(jwt: Jwt): Collection<GrantedAuthority> {
            val realmAccess = jwt.claims["realm_access"] as Map<String, Any>
            logger.info("code not reached")
            return (realmAccess["roles"] as List<String>).stream()
                    .map { roleName: String -> "ROLE_${roleName.toUpperCase()}" } // prefix to map to a Spring Security "role"
                    .map { role: String? -> SimpleGrantedAuthority(role) }
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
        }
    }
}
```